# Action in a context-menu uses selection of records

Tags: contextual-menu

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQkZFJ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I have a table where I let the users select records and then use this selection to "drill" to another report (open another report and use the selected records as a filter)

The action to open a drill is in a context menu, which opens when right clicked on any record.

Is it too confusing that the selection gets used for a drill and not the record where the user has clicked right?

Comment: It does seem a little confusing at first glance. Is there a particular reason why it's in the context menu and not a separate control below the table?

Comment: When we first used it, the users could only select one record at a time, so the right-click was on the record used for the drill. But then we wanted to increase the flexibility by allowing more selections and endet up with this. We had a version with a control below the table, but the users found it kinda odd, because the drill with one record (which is still used sometimes) would work with a context-menu

Answer (score 3):

To quote Microsoft: [The [context] menu items should apply only to the selected (or clicked upon) object or window region.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511502.aspx#contextMenus)

The selected records are still selected objects. You should make sure that the context to which the menu applies is clear.

A good example is Firefox context menu that appears when you right click within an iFrame - it shows actions related to the page and an extra item called "This Frame" to show extra actions in the context of the frame:

[image]

Therefore, I suggest you change the item name from "Drills" to something that better indicates the context - for example: "Selected Records".

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute "Selected" being checked is not to confuse with a row in the list being selected, or focused, for an upcoming action, like open (enter), delete or for actions from a toolbar. Let's dub this "list selection" for the moment. This is how you select for example a file in the Windows Explorer or Apple's Finder. You may do multiple *list selections* by holding shift or ctrl/cmd.

What you right click on is always the subject of the right click context menu. Do not put actions for any arbitrary record in the context of a another record. That way you would mix up the contexts.

For example, In Windows Explorer, the *list selection* even changes when you right click, to emphasize what context the context menu performs its actions on.

[image]

I would move your drill actions for sets of checked items to a toolbar next to the list, like for example Gmail does, and only keep them in the context menu if it makes sense to perform them on the *list selected* item or items.

[image]